# How to extract the max value of a string in R

Tags: r, text

I have a vector of strings like this:

```
"1111111221111122111111UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU"
"---1-1---1--111111"
"1111112111 1111" (with blank spaces)
```

everyone has different length and I want to extract the max value of the each string, for the three examples above the max values would be (2,1,2), but don't know how to do it with the letters or the dash or the blank spaces, all these three are the minimum, i.e., 1 is bigger than "U", "-" and " " and between them is the same.

Any advice?

Best regards

Comment: So, in each string, you want to remove anything that's not a number. I bet there's a SO question for that. Then you want to take unique characters in a string. I bet there's a SO question for that. Then you want to get the max of that. I'm betting you can guess the function to use for that. You can do it man!!!

Comment: What makes `2` "greater" than `U` ?

Comment: `x <- c("1111111221111122111111UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU", "---1-1---1--111111", "1111112111 1111");
y <- strsplit(x, "");
sapply(y, function(yi) max(as.numeric(yi), na.rm=TRUE))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decompose the problem into independent, solvable steps:

1. Transform the input into a suitable format
2. Find the maximum

The we get:

1. ```
   # Separate strings into individual characters
   digits_str = strsplit(input, '')
   # Convert to correct type
   digits = lapply(digits_str, as.integer)
   ```
2. ```
   # Perform actual logic, on each input string in turn.
   result = vapply(digits, max, integer(1L), na.rm = TRUE)
   ```

This uses the [`lapply` and `vapply` functions](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html) which allow you to [perform an operation (here first `as.integer` and then `max`) on all values in a vector/list](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-tutorial-apply-family).